# Kendo UI Customize Kendo Confirm OK button

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have this Kendo Confirm function here. What I want when click on `OK` it run this `grid.dataSource.remove(data)  grid.dataSource.sync()`. Can anyone help me how to achieve this?  Thanks in advance.

```js
function(e) { 
  return $("<div></div>").kendoConfirm({
    title: "My Title",
    content: "Are you sure to delete this record?",
    messages:{
      okText: "OK",
      cancel: "Cancel"
    }
  }).data("kendoConfirm").open().result;
  
  // if click OK run this
  // grid.dataSource.remove(data) 
  // grid.dataSource.sync()  
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Seem Kendo Confirm had limited [resources here](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/confirm). So I need to change to Kendo Dialog to for this method.

```js
function(e) {
  return $("<div></div>").kendoDialog({
    closable: false, // hide X
    title: "My Title",
    content: "Are you sure to delete this record?",
    actions: [{
      text: "OK",
      action: function(e){
        grid.dataSource.remove(data) 
        grid.dataSource.sync() 
        return true;
      },
      primary: true
      },{
        text: "Cancel"
    }]
  }).data("kendoDialog").open().center();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Saved me lot of time

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [shortcut function kendo.confirm](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/kendo/methods/confirm) which returns a promise and execute your logic when it's resolved:

```
kendo.confirm("Are you sure to delete this record?").then(function () {
    grid.dataSource.remove(data) 
    grid.dataSource.sync() 
});
```

Here's a demo and overview: https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dialog/predefined-dialogs

Comment: Thank you, I used this before. But the title will display my URL and to change that I need to use CSS. Plus I also need to customize the button.